# Where to find rpcauth.py for configuring rpcauth in bitcoin.conf on Ubuntu

Tags: bitcoind

I can't find the python file to create the rpc credentials. According to the documentation it should reside somewhere here:

> using the output from the script in share/rpcauth/rpcauth.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python file is not provided if you installed bitcoind through PPA.

You can download it yourself

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/master/share/rpcauth/rpcauth.py`

And run the program as follows

`python3 rpcauth.py myusername mysecretpassword`